# Python issue with module zipfile

Tags: python-2.7

I have written a piece code for extract a file. Here is my code:

```
import zipfile
zFile=zipfile.ZipFile("pyls.py.zip")
try:
    zFile.extractall(pwd="123456789")
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Although, password is correct but when i run it, it show : ('Bad password for file', ). I don't understand it. My os is debian and python version is 2.7
can you help me ?
thanks very much

Comment: What OS?  How did you create the file?

Comment: Did you create the password yourself?

Comment: I use Window 7 64 bit. I created file by Openssl. Password was entered when i created file .p12. Java version 1.6.